# validation of dynamically created fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, dynamic

can someone please put me in the right direction towards this code snippet?

```
function validateForm() {
    var flag=1;
//i have array containg values some values array[]
    $(document).ready(function () {
      alert("what happened");
      //my form contains dynamically generated input fields..
     //i can't seem to generate the ids.. 
    var y=$("#inputfield"+array[1]).val();// seems to me like error in this line
    //{validation code using y}
    flag = 0;
});
if (flag === 0) {

    return false;
}

}
```

here's the html part:

```
<form action="L4.php" method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm();">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: where is "inputfield+array[1]" element in your code?how are you adding this?

Comment: Look for jQuery Validation Plugin, all you have to do is just add required="true" in your dynamically generated fields and it will do the validation like that and much more.

Comment: Great You are calling `ready function` `on submitting the form`?

Comment: "inputfield" were dynamically generated having values 1, 2.. 3... that part of the code i didn't highlight.

Comment: @rohan, yep! is that not possible?

Comment: Generating id`s for dynamically generating fields is quite easy, you need to use a global variable initialized to zero and then each time when a new field is being created, increment the global variable and use it. like this `var idGen=0; for (....) { var newId="new"+(idGen++); // use this id for the newly generating field  }`

Comment: the best way use counter of the incremented input type pass that counter varaible from html page to the jQuery.from there start a loop and validate all the fields or you can use filter in jquery

Comment: $("<div />", { "class":"wrapper", id:"someid"+i })
   .append("Zone : ")
   .append($("<input />", { type: "text", name:"ZONE"+array[l], id:"ZONE"+array[i] required="true"})); like this? @Sumit

Comment: ok, if you have already created the fields with id`s in sequential order, then you can access it this way. ` var id= "#inputfield"+array[1] ; var y=$(id).val();` .hoping that array contains the numbers starting from 1 to  n

Comment: the problem is: var y=$("#inputfield"+array[0]); doesn't work, nor does element.getElementById(#inputfield"+array[0])

Comment: yes you can do that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var input= $('input').filter(function(){ return this.id.match("input_type");});

    $.each(input, function(i,obj){
            var id = "#"+$(input[i]).attr('id');
                    if(id.match(/Fname/)){
                          //do something
                    }else if(id.match(/Lname/)){
                         //do something  
                    }
        });
```

Comment: thank you for the response, may i know what id.match(/Fname/)  and/Lname/means? i'm not familiar with it.

Comment: what ever u have to match Fname is just a text i am matching same Lname or from the id u can check the values also like id.val()=="";whatever u want to test

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function validateForm() {
    var flag=1;
    $('form input[type="text"]').each(function(){//looping for all textboxes
        if($(this).val()=="")//if the textbox is empty
            flag=0;
    });
    if (flag === 0) {
        alert('error');
        return false;
    }
    return true;// if ok then return true
}
```